# Removing duplicate strings from lines in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, uniq

I am trying to remove duplicate strings within lines in a file. I tried using uniq, however this only works for removing duplicate lines, not duplicate strings in lines.

I only care about the "words" after the = sign and that "words" are any sequence of non-spaces but cannot contain = signs.

My file looks like the following:

```
LINE1=hello hello world
LINE2=hello world world
LINE3=hello hello hello
```

What I'd like it to look like:

```
LINE1=hello world
LINE2=hello world
LINE3=hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible interpretation of what you might be looking for:

```
$ awk -F'=' '{words=""; delete seen; split($2,t,/ /); for (i=1;i in t;i++) if (!seen[t[i]]++) words = (words=="" ? "" : words " ") t[i]; print $1 FS words}' file
LINE1=hello world
LINE2=hello world
LINE3=hello
```

It's based on a lot of assumptions but mainly that you only care about the "words" after the `=` sign and that "words" are any sequence of non-spaces but cannot contain `=` signs.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you

Comment: Fastest one wins!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this awk:

```
awk -F '[= ]' '{delete a; a[$2]++; printf "%s=%s", $1, $2; 
   for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf "%s%s", OFS, $i; print ""}' file

LINE1=hello world
LINE2=hello world
LINE3=hello
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="( |=)"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if(!seen[$i]++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==1?"=":OFS)} printf ORS; delete seen}' file
LINE1=hello world 
LINE2=hello world 
LINE3=hello
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF--{sub(/hello/,"world",$2)}/LINE3/{sub(/world/,"")}1' file

LINE1=hello world
LINE2=hello world
LINE3=hello
```